# WFFM FormDesigner error

Tags: wffm, sitecore-client

In Sitecore 8.1, opening FormDesigner gives the following error:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.Controls.FormSettingsDesigner.set_TitleTags(String[]
>   value) +26    Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.FormDesigner.LoadControls() +795
>   Sitecore.Forms.Shell.UI.FormDesigner.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +123
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +128
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   +146    Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +594
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +4498

The form is working fine, I think this is an upgrade issue.

Comment: I think you're right. That does seem to be an error in Sitecore. I think I would send that one to Sitecore Support to have them help figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Sitecore.Forms.dll version. If you upgraded your Sitecore instance then you also need to upgrade WFFM. Here you can find all WFFM versions - https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Web_Forms_For_Marketers.aspx